# AAR files uploaded to wrong path with Bintray multi-module project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray

I have a multi-module Android project and I'm trying to upload the files to Bintray for distribution via jCenter.

```
group = 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk'
version = '4.0.0'

ext {
  bintrayRepo = 'chat-sdk-android'
  bintrayName = 'chat-core'
  bintrayUserOrg = 'chat-sdk'

  publishedGroupId = 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk'
  libraryName = 'ChatSDKCore'
  artifact = 'chat-core'

  libraryDescription = 'Chat SDK Core library for Android'

  siteUrl = 'https://chatsdk.co'
  gitUrl = 'https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android.git'

  libraryVersion = '4.0.0'

  developerId = 'bensmiley'
  developerName = 'Ben Smiley-Andrews'
  developerEmail = 'ben@chatsdk.co'

  licenseName = 'Chat SDK License'
  licenseUrl = 'https://chatsdk.co/chat-sdk-license/'
  allLicenses = ['GPL-3.0']
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chat-
sdk/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chat-
sdk/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

This is my build script. The problem is that when I run `bintrayUpload` the resulting upload looks like this:

```
chat-core/
    /4.0.0/
       chat-core-4.0.0.pom
       chat-core-4.0.0.pom.asc
    /maven-metadata.xml

chat_sdk_core/
    /4.0.0/
        chat_sdk_core-4.0.0-sources.jar
        chat_sdk_core-4.0.0-sources.jar.asc
        chat_sdk_core-4.0.0.aar
        chat_sdk_core-4.0.0.aar.asc
```

So it looks like the Bintray plugin is assuming that the name for the source code should be taken as the module name rather than the one specified.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, I changed the names of the modules in android studio so they used dashes rather than underscores.